# Joining rows from two dataframes with the closest point

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, distance

Hi I am kinda new to spark and I am not sure how to approach this.

I have 2 tables (way smaller for easier explanation):

A:[Weather Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIK50.png)

B:[travel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbL3V.png)

I need to join these tables by finding the closest station when the trip started in the same date and do the same when the trip ended. so at the end I have all the weather data from the station at the time the trip started and when the trip finished, and just one row for each trip with the data from the closest weather station.

i have done something similar with geopandas and udf but it was way easier because i was looking for an interception. like this:

```
def find_state_gps(lat, long):
df = gdf_states.apply(lambda x: x["NAME"] if x["geometry"].intersects(Point(long,lat)) else None, axis =1)
idx = df.first_valid_index()
value = df.loc[idx] if idx is not None else "Not in USA territory"
return(value)

state_gps = udf(find_state_gps, StringType())
```

I am not sure how to handle the logic this time.

i also tried doing this query with no luck.

```
query = "SELECT STATION,\
    NAME,\
    LATITUDE,\
    LONGITUDE,\
    AWND,\
    p.id_trip,\
    p.Latitude,\
    p.Longitude,\
    p.startDate,\
      Abs(p.latitude-LATITUDE)**2 + Abs(p.Longitude-LONGITUDE)**2\
      AS dd\
FROM df2\
CROSS JOIN (\
SELECT id AS id_trip,\
        station_id,\
        Latitude,\
        Longitude,\
        startDate\
 FROM df1\
) AS p ON 1=1\
 ORDER BY dd"
```

and got the following error:
ParseException:
mismatched input '2' expecting {, ';'}(line 1, pos 189)

At the end i want something like this without repeated trips.

| id | started_date | finish_date | finished | weather_station_start | weather_station_end | more columns about weather for starting and ending trip locations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bim | baz | bim | baz | bim | bim |
| 2 | bim | baz | bim | baz | bim | bim |

I really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `intersects` method of _Spark_, that targets mainly arrays of data, will be able to react like the `ST_Intersects` function that you can find in GIS databases like _PostGIS_. In case you encounter problems later with that, maybe one solution could be to use `geotools` API (or another one) to do that checking in an UDF function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your sample data a bit because all stations have the same coordinates:

```
travel_data  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('0','2013-06-01','00:00:01','-73.98915076','40.7423543','40.74317449','-74.00366443','2013-06-01')
,('1','2013-06-01','00:00:08','-73.98915076','40.7423543','40.74317449','-74.00366443','2013-06-01')
,('2','2013-06-01','00:00:44','-73.99595065','40.69512845','40.69512845','-73.99595065','2013-06-01')
,('3','2013-06-01','00:01:04','-73.98758561','40.73524276','40.6917823','-73.9737299','2013-06-01')
,('4','2013-06-01','00:01:22','-74.01677685','40.70569254','40.68926942','-73.98912867','2013-06-01')
  ], ['id','startDate','startTime','Longitude','Latitude','end station latitude','end station longitude','stopdate']
)

weather_data  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
 ('USINYWC0003','WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 3, NY US','41.0639','-73.7722','71','2013-06-01','','','','','')
,('USINYWC0002','WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 2, NY US','41.0638','-73.7723','71','2013-06-02','','','','','')
,('USINYWC0001','WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US','41.0635','-73.7724','71','2013-06-03','','','','','')
  ], ['STATION','NAME','LATITUDE','LONGITUDE','ELEVATION','DATE','AWND','AWND ATTRIBUTES','DAPR','DAPR ATTRIBUTES','DASE']
)

+---+----------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id| startDate|startTime|   Longitude|   Latitude|end station latitude|end station longitude|  stopdate|
+---+----------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  0|2013-06-01| 00:00:01|-73.98915076| 40.7423543|         40.74317449|         -74.00366443|2013-06-01|
|  1|2013-06-01| 00:00:08|-73.98915076| 40.7423543|         40.74317449|         -74.00366443|2013-06-01|
|  2|2013-06-01| 00:00:44|-73.99595065|40.69512845|         40.69512845|         -73.99595065|2013-06-01|
|  3|2013-06-01| 00:01:04|-73.98758561|40.73524276|          40.6917823|          -73.9737299|2013-06-01|
|  4|2013-06-01| 00:01:22|-74.01677685|40.70569254|         40.68926942|         -73.98912867|2013-06-01|
+---+----------+---------+------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+----------+

+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----+---------------+----+---------------+----+
|    STATION|                NAME|LATITUDE|LONGITUDE|ELEVATION|      DATE|AWND|AWND ATTRIBUTES|DAPR|DAPR ATTRIBUTES|DASE|
+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----+---------------+----+---------------+----+
|USINYWC0003|WHITE PLAINS 3.1 ...| 41.0639| -73.7722|       71|2013-06-01|    |               |    |               |    |
|USINYWC0002|WHITE PLAINS 3.1 ...| 41.0638| -73.7723|       71|2013-06-02|    |               |    |               |    |
|USINYWC0001|WHITE PLAINS 3.1 ...| 41.0635| -73.7724|       71|2013-06-03|    |               |    |               |    |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----+---------------+----+---------------+----+
```

Then, crossjoin the two dataframes in order to calculate the haversine distance between the start/end point and all stations. Not the best solution using a crossjoin, but depending on the size of your data it might be the easiest way

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, radians, asin, sin, sqrt, cos, max, min
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

join_df = travel_data\
    .crossJoin(weather_data.select('NAME',col('LATITUDE').alias('st_LAT'),col('LONGITUDE').alias('st_LON'), 'AWND')) \
    .withColumn("dlon_start", radians(col("st_LON")) - radians(col("Longitude"))) \
    .withColumn("dlat_start", radians(col("st_LAT")) - radians(col("Latitude"))) \
    .withColumn("haversine_dist_start", asin(sqrt(
                                         sin(col("dlat_start") / 2) ** 2 + cos(radians(col("Latitude")))
                                         * cos(radians(col("st_LAT"))) * sin(col("dlon_start") / 2) ** 2
                                         )
                                    ) * 2 * 3963 * 5280)\
    .withColumn("dlon_end", radians(col("st_LON")) - radians(col("end station longitude"))) \
    .withColumn("dlat_end", radians(col("st_LAT")) - radians(col("end station latitude"))) \
    .withColumn("haversine_dist_end", asin(sqrt(
                                         sin(col("dlat_end") / 2) ** 2 + cos(radians(col("Latitude")))
                                         * cos(radians(col("st_LAT"))) * sin(col("dlon_end") / 2) ** 2
                                         )
                                    ) * 2 * 3963 * 5280)\
    .drop('dlon_start','dlat_start','dlon_end','dlat_end')
```

Finally, using window functions to pick the closest station from start point (result1) and closest station from end point (result2)

```
W = W.partitionBy("id")

result1 = join_df\
    .withColumn("min_dist_start", min('haversine_dist_start').over(W))\
    .filter(col("min_dist_start") == col('haversine_dist_start'))\
    .select('id',col('startDate').alias('started_date'),col('stopdate').alias('finish_date'),col('NAME').alias('weather_station_start'),col('Latitude').alias('Latitude_start'),col('Longitude').alias('Longitude_start'))



result2 = join_df\
    .withColumn("min_dist_end", min('haversine_dist_end').over(W))\
    .filter(col("min_dist_end") == col('haversine_dist_end'))\
    .select('id', col('NAME').alias('weather_station_end'))

final = result1.join(result2, 'id', 'left')

final.show()
```

Not sure of wich columns you want on the output but hope this give you some insights
output:

```
+---+------------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|id |started_date|finish_date|weather_station_start        |Latitude_start|Longitude_start|weather_station_end          |
+---+------------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|0  |2013-06-01  |2013-06-01 |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|40.7423543    |-73.98915076   |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|
|1  |2013-06-01  |2013-06-01 |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|40.7423543    |-73.98915076   |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|
|2  |2013-06-01  |2013-06-01 |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|40.69512845   |-73.99595065   |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|
|3  |2013-06-01  |2013-06-01 |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|40.73524276   |-73.98758561   |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|
|4  |2013-06-01  |2013-06-01 |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|40.70569254   |-74.01677685   |WHITE PLAINS 3.1 NNW 1, NY US|
+---+------------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```