# Optimized way to join pyspark dataframes on closest distance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, distance

I'm trying to join the [GHCN](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/) weather dataset and another dataset:

**Weather Dataset:** (called "weather" in the code)

| station_id | date | PRCP | SNOW | SNWD | TMAX | TMIN | Latitude | Longitude | Elevation | State | date_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA001010235 | 19730707 | null | null | 0.0 | 0.0 | null | 48.4 | -123.4833 | 17.0 | BC | 1973-07-07 |
| CA001010235 | 19780337 | 14 | 8 | 0.0 | 0.0 | null | 48.4 | -123.4833 | 17.0 | BC | 1978-03-30 |
| CA001010595 | 19690607 | null | null | 0.0 | 0.0 | null | 48.5833 | -123.5167 | 17.0 | BC | 1969-06-07 |

**Species Dataset:** (called "ebird" in the code where "ebird_id" is unique for each row in the dataset)

| speciesCode | comName | sciName | locId | locName | ObsDt | howMany | lat | lng | obsValid | obsReview | locationPrivate | subId | ebird_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nswowl | Northern Saw-whet Owl | Aegolius acadicus | L787133 | Kumdis Slough | 2017-03-20 23:15 | 1 | 53.7392187 | -132.1612358 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | S35611913 | eff-178121-fff |
| wilsni1 | Wilson's Snipe | Gallinago delicata | L1166559 | Hornby Island--Ford Cove | 2017-03-20 21:44 | 1 | 49.4973435 | -124.6768427 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | S35323282 | abc-1920192-fff |
| cacgoo1 | Cackling Goose | Branta hutchinsii | L833055 | Central Saanich--»æIKEL (Maber Flats) | 2017-03-20 19:24 | 5 | 48.5724686 | -123.4305167 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | S35322116 | yhj-9102910-fff |

**Result Expected:** I need to join these tables by finding the closest weather station for each row in the species dataset for the same date. So in this example, ebird_id "eff-178121-fff" is closest to the weather station "CA001010235" and the distance is around 20 kms.

| speciesCode | comName | sciName | locId | locName | ObsDt | howMany | lat | lng | obsValid | obsReview | locationPrivate | subId | ebird_id |  | station_id | date | PRCP | SNOW | SNWD | TMAX | TMIN | Latitude | Longitude | Elevation | State | date_final | distance(kms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nswowl | Northern Saw-whet Owl | Aegolius acadicus | L787133 | Kumdis Slough | 2017-03-20 23:15 | 1 | 53.7392187 | -132.1612358 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | S35611913 | eff-178121-fff |  | CA001010235 | 20170320 | null | null | 0.0 | 0.0 | null | 48.4 | -123.4833 | 17.0 | BC | 2017-03-20 | 20 |
| wilsni1 | Wilson's Snipe | Gallinago delicata | L1166559 | Hornby Island--Ford Cove | 2017-03-20 21:44 | 1 | 49.4973435 | -124.6768427 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | S35323282 | abc-1920192-fff |  | CA001010595 | 20170320 | null | null | 0.0 | 0.0 | null | 48.5833 | -123.5167 | 17.0 | BC | 2017-03-20 |  |

**What I have tried so far:** I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230505/joining-rows-from-two-dataframes-with-the-closest-point) and it works for a sample of the datasets but when I tried to run the below code for the entire weather and entire species dataset, the cross join worked but the partitionBy and windows function line was taking too long. I also tried replacing the partionBy and windows function with pyspark SQL queries in case that would be faster but it's still taking time. Is there any optimized way to do this?

```
join_df = ebird.crossJoin(weather).withColumn("dist_longit", radians(weather["Longitude"]) - radians(ebird["lng"])).withColumn("dist_latit", radians(weather["Latitude"]) - radians(ebird["lat"]))

join_df = join_df.withColumn("haversine_distance_kms", asin(sqrt(
                                         sin(join_df["dist_latit"] / 2) ** 2 + cos(radians(join_df["lat"]))
                                         * cos(radians(join_df["Latitude"])) * sin(join_df["dist_longit"] / 2) ** 2
                                         )
                                    ) * 2 * 6371).drop("dist_longit","dist_latit")
W = W.partitionBy("ebird_id")
result = join_df.withColumn("min_dist", min(join_df['haversine_distance_kms']).over(W))\
.filter(col("min_dist") == col('haversine_distance_kms'))

print(result.show(1))
```

Edit:

**Size of the datasets:**

```
print(weather.count()) #output: 8211812
print(ebird.count()) #output: 1564574
```

Comment: What is the size of each of the 2 datasets, also can you add screenshots of your application spark u ?

Comment: Edited the post to add it - the species (i.e. ebird) one is 1564574 and the weather one is 8211812

Comment: Give us a sample of input df and expected output, your code is not as useful especially if it is not working

Comment: Also, could you please not use images for code? The reasons why are explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) :) This will greatly improve the quality of your post!

Comment: Added data as a table instead of an image so should be more readable now